# Bring non-EU parent in Switzerland after becoming Swiss citizen

Tags: switzerland

I tried to find information about this, but without success.

Let's say that a non-EU national becomes a Swiss citizen by living in Switzerland for a certain amount of time and by satisfying all of the other requirements. Or by facilitated naturalization through marriage.

My question is, is it possible to then bring your non-EU parent to Switzerland given the fact that all of the expenses will be covered by me (insurance, living space, living expense etc.)?

Does the parent has to already depend on you (eg. financially) for this to happen? Any links to appropriate laws or cases would be highly appreciated!

Comment: As far as you're a citizen of a country and you're capable to (show that you can) maintain financially your relative, then you can bring that relative in the country. This applies for every other country. It doesn't have to be a burden on the social system of that country.

Comment: This is valid for any other financially capable person that is not a citizen, let alone a citizen.